# Send files from a branch in one repo to a branch in another repo (repos are not in same account)

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, bitbucket, devops

I need to send release files to a branch in prod repo from a branch in nonprod repo using groovy (jenkins pipeline). Repos are not in same account.

- Is it possible to send files from a repo to repo, that are in different accounts?

I'm using bitbucket.

So far I've tried,

```
stage("Create a branhc in remote Repo"){
    steps{
       script{
        withCredentials([[$class: 'usernamePasswordMultiBinding",
                    credentialsId: '####',
                    usernameVariable: '###',
                    passwordVariable: '###',]])

        stdout = sh(script: 'git checkout -b release/1.0.1', returnStdout: true)
        sh(script:'git push origin release/1.0.1 remote repo url')

}}}
```

When I run this I get following error,
java.lang.IllegalStateException: withCredentials step must be called with a body

I'm trying to create a new branch in the remote repo here.
By remote repo I mean a repo in another git hub account (in prod env).

Comment: Yes is possible.  But for more details on how to do it you need improve your question and  add more information like, what you had tried so far, examples, shows us your groovy code...

Comment: Updated the question. Could you please check?

Comment: As far as Git is concerned, `git push` deals with *commits*, not files. (The commits then hold files: each commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*.) You must therefore make commits. But you're not even getting to Git yet, as you're having some kind of issue with your Jenkins steps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found was to clone the branch to a folder and remove the .git from the folder.

```
sh script: "rm -rf .git"
```

Then initialize a new git inside the same folder and push it to the repository I want.

```
dir("folder"){
    sh script: "git init"
    sh script: "git add *"
    sh script: 'git commit -m "new branch created"'
    sh script: "git checkout -b ${new_branch}"
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                       credentialsId: 'mycred',
                       usernameVariable: 'username',
                       passwordVariable: 'pass']]){
    sh('git push https://${username}:${pass}@git.example.com:8080/scm/user/reponame ${new_branch})
}
```